# Tab Icon Changing from Custom to React icon. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on some app and have this weird issue where the tab icon keeps switching from the (right) one I set to the ReactJS icon, as I navigate between routes. In my HTML file, I have the icon appropriately linked (or at least I'd presume), so what's wrong?

This is especially bizarre given the fact that I'm not even using React but rather Vue.js 2. What's happening, and how do I solve this?

I'm not sure code snippets would help but below is my root HTML.

**HTML head section**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>RGB Guessing Game</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./static/colors.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>
```

Also, here are photos the two tab icon versions

**Right version**

[image]

**Wrong (React) version**

[image]

Comment: Check directory route

Comment: @YoungKyunJin It is just fine, hence why it's working for some routes. Problem is, why is it being replaced by the React icon when navigating to other routes when I don't even have the React icon in any of my project's folders, let alone work with it?

Answer (score 4):

In the public folder, there is a file called manifest.json.  Inside the file is a section on icons.  Just change the name of the icon to your specific one.  Also in the public folder is index.html.  Find the line that says .  Change the name there too.

Comment: When I have tried pasting and replacing the favicon icon inside the public folder it just resets automatically back to its original form. The file itself inside the folder! Wth is this? And your response isnt really a solution as in you replace the content, the name can stay the same..